# find all dictionaries that each have an indeterminate number of defined keys

Tags: python

I have information about a bunch of different items. Each item has its own dictionary filled with information about that item, and I have a larger dictionary in which each item is stored. I do not, however, have all the same information for each item. For instance, let's say my items are fruit. Then the structure looks like:

```
fruit = {}
fruit['apple'] = {'color': 'red', 'origin': 'Washington'}
fruit['banana'] = {'color': 'yellow'}
fruit['orange'] = {'color': 'orange', 'origin': 'Florida'}
```

If I want to find origin of each fruit for which it has been defined, I am doing the following:

```
fruits, origins = zip(* [(f, fruit[f]['origin']) for f in fruit.keys() if 'origin' in fruit[f]])
```

That works fine. It starts getting ugly once I want to find every fruit that has both a color and origin defined.

```
fruits, origins, colors = zip(* [(f, fruit[f]['origin'], fruit[f]['color']) for f in fruit.keys() if 'origin' in fruit[f] and 'color' in fruit[f]])
```

What I would like to do is be able to write a general function that will perform this action for any number of specified keys. That is, I could call some function called "defined" that would take a dictionary of dictionaries, and a key or list of keys within a sub-dictionary, and return all of the sub-dictionaries that have definitions for each of those keys, as well as the values for each key.

```
fruits, origins = defined(fruit, ['origin'])
fruits, origins, colors = defined(fruit, ['origin', 'color'])
```

I've looked at a variety of existing threads with questions about getting key/value pairs out of or in to dictionaries, but I have not found anything that looks right. Is there a reasonably straightforward way to generalize this?

Or, if people also want to tell me that I should be organizing my data in entirely different way, I would also welcome that. I initially settled on a dictionary of dictionaries because of the wide range of information available for each item. For instance, some sub-dictionaries have tens of entries with information, and some items only have a few entries (that is, the 'apple' dictionary has a lot of information, but I do not have much stored in 'kumquat').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generalize the value extraction by a list comprehension, and the `and` sequence by `all`:

```
def defined(dct, keys):
    return zip(*[([k] + [v[m] for m in keys])
                 for k, v in dct.iteritems()
                 if all(m in v for m in keys)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that returns the data in a slightly different way than suggested by your example calls: it will return an iterator that iterates over all the dictionary entries that have all required fields.

```
def defined(fruits, attr_names):
    getter = operator.itemgetter(*attr_names)
    for f, d in fruit.iteritems():
        try:
            attrs = getter(d)
        except KeyError:
            continue
        else:
            yield (f,) + attrs
```

The only thing in the implementation that might be worth mentioning is  `operator.itemgetter()`.  A call like

```
operator.itemgetter(['origin', 'color'])
```

returns a function that, applied to a dictionary, will return the values for the keys `'origin'` and `'color'` as a tuple.  If one of the keys can't be lookep up, the dictionary will throw a `KeyError` as usual.

You can use `zip()` on the returned iterator to use this function in the way you suggested:

```
fruits, origins, colors = zip(*defined(fruit, ['origin', 'color']))
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for the toy example I gave. For some reason, I cannot get it to work for my real problem, but I'm going to play with this further and try to understand what exactly this is doing.